# Make SKSprites register collision but not affect each other

Tags: ios, swift3, collision

Im wanting to add powerups to my game but when my sprite hits the powerup sprite it throws him off course because the game has registered a collision and i guess physics come into play, when i tap the screen my sprite jumps in the air, hits the powerup and stops moving up and falls down again.

I need the sprite to jump up, collect the powerup sprite and the score go up (score going up code is done) but i cannot figure out how to make the 2 sprites no register the collision.

```
    //Create the PowerUp Coin to add score
func createCoin() {

    coinPlus5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "coin1")
    coinPlus5.name = "coinPlus5"
    coinPlus5.position.x = self.frame.size.width*2.6
    coinPlus5.position.y = CGFloat.randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: -(self.frame.size.height / 2.8), secondNum: (self.frame.size.height / 2.4))
    coinPlus5.zPosition = 11
    coinPlus5.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    hitPowerup = false

    // Add Physics Bodys
    coinPlus5.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: coinPlus5.texture!, size: CGSize(width: coinPlus5.size.width, height: coinPlus5.size.height))


    //enemyBird1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.height/13)
    coinPlus5.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    coinPlus5.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    coinPlus5.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    // Add Collision Bitmasks
    coinPlus5.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Pipes
```

And the character sprite code is:

```
 func initialise() {

    self.name = "Bird"
    self.zPosition = 3
    self.size = CGSize(width: 130, height: 110)
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)






    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: self.texture!,
                                     size: CGSize(width: self.size.width,
                                                  height: self.size.height))

    // Add Physics Bodys
    self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.physicsBody?.mass = CGFloat(-100)
    // Add Collision Bitmasks
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Bird
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Ground | ColliderType.Pipes
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Ground | ColliderType.Pipes | ColliderType.Score


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your coin's physics category is `ColliderType.Pipes`. You've set the bird's `collisionBitMask` to collide with both ground and pipes (`ColliderType.Ground | ColliderType.Pipes`). This means that your player will have physics collision with the coins.

To fix this, you probably want a new collider type for coins. You'll want coins to be a part of the player's `contactTestBitMask` so you can detect when the player gets a coin, but **not** part of the player's `collisionBitMask` so they don't affect your physics.

Comment: Great! Good luck with your game.